# Drupal 7 view display description of term

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I would like to display a description of a vocabulary term. I have terms like parent - child, and the problem comes when I'm trying to display child's description, it shows only parrent's description. So when I have term with ID 22 which is child of parrent with ID 5, It displays description of ID 5.

I am not able to reproduce this kind problem, when I match url taxonomy/term/22 my contextual filter has Taxanomy term from ID setup. So it should work fine.

Is there anything I miss?

Comment: Did you use custom template rendering or default term displaying ?

Comment: Just default, view

Comment: With view module or core ? 
With views this can help : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/209232/how-to-display-vocabulary-terms-and-their-descriptions-with-their-tagged-content

Also you can try this module : https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_display
AND https://www.drupal.org/node/1254878